# Скачивание файла по нажатию кнопки

Tags: angularjs, rest

Необходимо, чтобы при нажатии кнопки происходило скачивание файла.
Делал следующим образом. Это работает только если перейти по ссылке *"localhost:8080/api/act/printform/21"*, а надо ***по нажатию кнопки***.

**Контролер**

```
angular.module('app', []).controller('ActController', ['$scope' , 'ActService',  function($scope, ActService) {    
   $scope.createAct = function () {
        ActService.getPrintform(21);   
    };
}]);
```

**Сервис**

```
angular.module('app').service('ActService',function($http) {
   this.getPrintform = function(id) {
      query = "api/act/printform/" + id;
      return $http.get(query);
   };
});
```

**REST**

```
@GET
@Path("/printform/{id : \\d+}")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
public Response getPrintForm(@PathParam("id") BigDecimal id) {
        ActReport actReport = new ActReport();
        ActDTO actDTO = new ActTransform().getDTO(actService.getById(id));

        byte[] content = actReport.createAct(actDTO);
        ResponseBuilder rb = Response.ok(content);
        rb.header("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename="
                + "reportBy" + actDTO.getId() +".pdf");
        rb.header("Content-Length", content.length);
        rb.header("Content-Type", "application/download");
        return rb.build();          
    }
```

**web.xml**

```
 <web-app>
    <display-name>MavenSite</display-name>  
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>RestServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>ru.maven.rs</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>RestServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            10
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Подскажите, как исправить.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если опустить все подробности с ангуляром и xml, то в html скачивание pdf и jpg по ссылке делается вот так: http://htmlbook.ru/html/a/download